General Solution to Maxwell's Equations with Duhamel's Principle
In one dimension, it is easy to prove that if two solutions $\{u_1, u_2\}$ are known to $\mathcal{L}u(t) = 0$ where $\mathcal{L} \equiv{a(t)\partial_t^2+b(t)\partial_t+c(t)}$, the general solution to the associated inhomogeneous equation $\mathcal{L}U=g$ is given by:
$$U(t) = -u_1\int_{t_0}^t\mathrm{d}s\frac{g(s)u_2(s)}{a(s)\mathcal{W}(u_1,u_2)}+u_2\int_{t_0}^t\mathrm{d}s\frac{g(s)u_1(s)}{a(s)\mathcal{W}(u_1,u_2)}+c_1u_1 + c_2u_2\tag{1}$$
Where $\mathcal{W}(u_1,u_2) \equiv\dot{u}_2u_1-\dot{u}_1u_2$. I know that the formula (1) is a special case of "Duhamel's principle" which can be used to extend (1) to arbitrary functions $\mathcal{u}(t_1, t_2,\ldots)$. However, I'm having a hard time finding material on Duhamel's principle which answers the following question:
Maxwell's equations in Lorenz gauge can be expressed as:
$$\Box{\mathbf{A}}=\mathbf{J}\tag{2}$$
$$\Box{\phi}=\rho\tag{3}$$
The intuition I get from the method of variation of parameters (1) and its extension as Duhamel's principle is that since the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation of (2), namely $\Box\mathbf{A}_h=0$ can be written as:
$$\mathbf{A}_{h} = \mathbf{A}_h^+ + \mathbf{A}_h^-\equiv\sum_{\mu=1,2}\int\mathrm{d}^3k~\hat{\mathbf{\epsilon}}_{\mu_k}~a(\mathbf{k})~e^{i(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}-c|\mathbf{k}|t)}+\text{c.c.}\tag{4}$$
With a similar form for the solution to the associated homogeneous equation of (3), that there should be kernel functions $K^+$ and $K^-$ related in some way to $\mathbf{J}$, such that the general solution to (2) -- assuming that $\mathbf{J}$ is not a function of $\mathbf{A}$ --  is:
$$\mathbf{A} = c_+\mathbf{A}^+_h + c_-\mathbf{A}^-_h+\mathbf{A}^-_h\int\mathrm{d}^4r~K^+\mathbf{A}^+_h+\mathbf{A}^+_h\int\mathrm{d}^4r~K^-\mathbf{A}^-_h\tag{5}$$
Where (5) is constructed to be exactly analogous to (1). My problem is that I can't make out from the material available on Duhamel's principle whether this intuition is correct or how I might go about determining the form of those kernel functions.
Any help would be appreciated!

You seem to only know this in the context of mathematics. In physics literature we tend to cover the same idea under the name of Green's functions. Your intuition is correct; Maxwell's equations can be solved (for any specific choice of the gauge), by splitting the problem into "inhomogeneous but simplest boundary" and "homogeneous boundary value problem", and then you can express them all as integrals. https://galileoandeinstein.phys.virginia.edu/Elec_Mag/2022_Lectures/EM_39_Greens_Functions.html

Maxwell equations are redundant. The proper way to treat them is to first eliminate the redundancies. Doing so leads to working with the normal variables. The free space solution of Maxwell equations expressed in terms the Normal variables is easily obtained.
Ref:
Photons and Atoms
Introduction to Quantum electrodynamics
Claude Cohen-Tannoudji
page 23
